This is a time travel movie with a child that keeps going to the past where he meets a boy and eventually saves him from falling into a well
This is a live action movie. The child, a boy, I think, moves to an odd house where he finds passages into the past of the house and its family. He becomes friend to a boy there. Somehow what happened here in the past changes his own family for the worst. (I wish I could remember more.)
There was also a well which, in the future, he was warned to stay away from.  I think he has to save the boy in the past from that well, and that this will fix the problems in his family as well.

Can you estimate when this was released or at least when you saw it?

Could this be A Boy Called Red, not a movie but an episode of the anthology TV series Creeped Out?

Vincent is transported back into his grumpy father's past only a week before the tragic accident that changed his father's life forever. The death of his best friend, Red.


Per the wiki, his father's friend fell down a well and seemingly died.
